# ruby 1.8.7 gems are installed but-- they aren't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 2.3.5 app and if I try to do rake db:migrate, I get:

```
Missing these required gems:
  authlogic  ~> 2.1.3
  will_paginate  ~> 2.3.11
  paperclip  ~> 2.3.1.1
  mimetype-fu  ~> 0.1.2
  nokogiri  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.302 at /usr/local/bin/ruby18
  rubygems 1.8.3 at /home/p/patrick/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

yet if I do:

```
rake gems
```

I see:

```
    [F] authlogic ~> 2.1.3
    [F] will_paginate ~> 2.3.11
    [F] paperclip ~> 2.3.1.1
    [F] mimetype-fu ~> 0.1.2
    [R] rubyzip ~> 0.9.1
    [F] nokogiri 

    I = Installed
    F = Frozen
    R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

My config/environment.rb has in it:

```
config.gem 'authlogic',     :version => '~> 2.1.3'
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.11',  :source => 'http://gemcutt
config.gem 'paperclip',     :version => '~> 2.3.1.1'
config.gem 'mimetype-fu',   :lib => 'mimetype_fu',    :version => '~> 0.1.2'
config.gem 'rubyzip',       :lib => 'zip/ziprequire', :version => '~> 0.9.1'
config.gem 'nokogiri'
```

Comment: Have you tried running `rake gems:install` as requested?

Comment: yes..  after that running rake gems showed the list with the [F], [R] listing.

Comment: now if only someone could help me with my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing rvm on the server and all this nonsense went away..  yay for rvm!

Answer (score 1):

```
config.gem 'authlogic',     :version => '>= 2.1.3'
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '>= 2.3.11',  :source => 'http://gemcutt
config.gem 'paperclip',     :version => '>= 2.3.1.1'
config.gem 'mimetype-fu',   :lib => 'mimetype_fu',    :version => '>= 0.1.2'
config.gem 'rubyzip',       :lib => 'zip/ziprequire', :version => '>= 0.9.1'
config.gem 'nokogiri'
```

I don't know what `~>` means but this version should work properly

Comment: Ummm.  no that will not solve the problem.  Regarding "~>", read: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74

Comment: The `:source` for `will_paginate` looks incomplete.